# Estoy usando lo que es VS Code Studio, pero no se cual de estas extensiones me son útiles y cuales son innecesarias y debería de eliminar:

Tags: javascript, html, css, extensiones

1. Ayu
2. Bookmarks
3. Bracket pair colorizer
4. Code runner
5. ESLint
6. GitLens – Git supercharged
7. intelliSense for css class names in HTML
8. live server
9. vscode-icons

Comment: dos cosas, la primera es que este tipo de preguntas sobre opiniones no son muy bien recibidas en el canal,  y la otra es que las extensiones que te pueden servir dependen de el lenguaje y framework que vas a programar, hay muchos consejos en google, pero busca especifico para el framework, que tu vas a usar.